# Why do Nix lambdas and the ? operator interact like so?

Tags: nix, nixos

While trying out nix & nix repl:

```
Welcome to Nix version 2.3.6. Type :? for help.

nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}

nix-repl> builtins.typeOf pkgs
"set"

nix-repl> pkgs ? "firefox"
true

nix-repl> func = (n: pkgs ? "firefox")

nix-repl> func null
true

nix-repl> func = (n: pkgs ? n)

nix-repl> func "firefox"
false
```

I assumed that `func "firefox"` would return `true`.

What Nix paradigms or concepts explain why `func "firefox"` returns `false` in this example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The thing you write after `?` is not an expression: it is an attribute path.  This allows you to do powerful things like `pkgs ? hello.src` which probes to see whether `pkgs` has an attribute named `hello` which has an attribute named `src`.

When Nix evaluates `a ? b`, Nix just looks at the name "b", it does not consider whether "b" is a variable in the local context.  So `pkgs ? n` is true if an only if `pkgs` is a set with a member that literally is named "n".

Here is an example repl session that explores the issue.  The last line shows a possible solution for what I think you are trying to do.

```
nix-repl> pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {}
nix-repl> pkgs ? "firefox"
true
nix-repl> pkgs ? "name"
false
nix-repl> name = "firefox"
nix-repl> pkgs ? name
false
nix-repl> firefox = "name"
nix-repl> pkgs ? firefox
true
nix-repl> pkgs ? "${name}"
true
nix-repl> builtins.hasAttr name pkgs  
true
```

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, your 3rd example is showing that `pkgs ? firefox` and `pkgs ? "firefox"`, and finally `builtins.hasAttr "firefox" pkgs` are all equivalent?